# Неверный расчёт полного процессорного времени в System.Diagnostics.Process и что с этим делать?

Tags: c#, процесс, процессор

Доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
1. Запускаю программу с помощью стандартного функционала C# для работы с процессами с параметрами `createnowindow = true` и `shellexecute = false`. При завершении работы запускаемой программы вывожу её `TotalProcessTime`.

Не маловажным фактом является то, что запускаемая таким способом программа состоит из бесконечного цикла, без пауз и т.д.

Стандартный  виндузовский Task Manager показывает при её работе 100% нагрузки на процессор, а после "насильственного" завершения её работы моя программа показывает, что использовано 0 (!) процессорного времени.

**Вопрос:** почему так получается и как получить реальные данные?

**UPD 1:** Код получения полного процессорного времени

```
//proc - переменная типа System.Diagnostics.Process
proc.Refresh();
TimeSpan pts = proc.TotalProcessorTime;
Console.WriteLine(pts.TotalMilliseconds); //вот это, собственно, и не сходится
bool checker = (int)Math.Round(pts.TotalMilliseconds) > timeLimit;
if (checker)
    doProcessorTimeLimit();
```

Comment: Стоит показать код измерения и указать точно, какие данные не сходятся.

Comment: @defaultlocale добавил

Comment: Отлично! Вопрос: процесс запускается и завершается в самой программе или извне?

Comment: @defaultlocale завершается с помощью метода `Kill()`. Проверял на возможные ошибки с моей стороны - когда запускаю "нормальные" консольные программы без такого цикла, но завершаю их работу всё тем же методом, процессорное время рассчитывается правильно...